# Docker (Dockerfile): Share a directory from host to container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I would like to know if there's any way that I can share a directory from my host machine to the docker container (Shared Volume) using Dockerfile.

I understand that we can do that using volumes (-v option) while using docker run. But I couldn't find any way by which I can do that while using an Instruction of Dockerfile.

I already tried VOLUME instruction in Dockerfile but couldn't succeed.
Here's some details about my environment:

```
[me@myHost new]$ tree -L 1
.
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- Dockerfile
|-- Shared  // This is the directory I wish to share with my containers.
```

`
I was using **docker-compose.yml** file to mount this directory till now:

```
volumes:
- ./Shared:/shared  # "Relative Path at the host":"Absolute Path at the container"
```

But now, due to some reasons, I need to mount it in **Dockerfile**. I already tried the following but couldn't succeed (It is creating a new empty volume at /shared.):

```
VOLUME ./Shared:/shared
```

I could use docker run and save the image by making manual changes in the container, but I wished if I could do that in Dockerfile itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mount a local directory using commands in a Dockerfile. You must do this with `docker run`, or a proxy to `docker run` like `docker-compose`.

Comment: Well I thought the same.. Just wanted to confirm.. Ended up copying and removing the files while in docker-build.  Thanks.